# Jar files in war file able to depend on each other

Tags: java, jar, war

Quick question :

This is working for me but I'm not exactly sure how.. would like to know and have been Googling for ages can't find specifically this question

I have a war file which contains 3 jar files in it's WEB-INF\lib, on which it depends.  Now the thing is that one of the jar files in the lib folder also depends on classes in the other 2 jar files, and it's able to see these, with no instructions in the manifest file.  The war file is deployed in WebLogic.

Can you help re enlighten me ?  thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[Java Class loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader) does the job.

The Java Classloader is a part of the Java Runtime Environment that dynamically loads Java classes into the Java Virtual Machine. Usually classes are only loaded on demand.

If you notice there will be a manifest file for war file that includes all the jars the webapp needed.

Comment: yes, the manifest file for the war file does not contain any classpath elements ...  neither do the jar files that are contained... this is why I'm confused.  I'll explain a bit more : There are 3 contained jar files - 2 of the contained jar files are my code, built by my Ant script in Jenkins, the third contained jar is log4j.jar.